# Multi-row text box in dialog

Tags: dialog, dm-script

How can I create a text box that allows line breaks (by hitting Enter) and copies this to string?

I am trying to produce a dialog similar to the Image Info textbox in Digital Micrograph. This textbox will be used to create a text annotation which is created on the front-most image.

DLGCreateTextBox can create a multiple line text box but it does not seem to allow line breaks.

I searched [DM Scripting](http://www.gatan.com/resources/scripts) and the [TU Graz script database](http://portal.tugraz.at/portal/page/portal/felmi/DM-Script/DM-Script-Database) page but didn't see anything that uses such a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, dialog TextBoxes are not the most convenient dialog items in DigitalMicrograph scripted dialogs. There are a some points one needs to know:

- The text can only be set to (or read from) the item, while the dialog is displayed.
- The textbox is specified by *width* & *height* but also by a *length* parameter.
- As long as the text in the textbox is shorter than *length*, any return-keystroke will be stored as character.
- However, if the limit has been reached, the return-keystroke is passed on to the dialog. In case it is a modal dialog (i.e. displayed by `pose()`), the return-keystroke will immediately act as 'okay' and close the dialog!

With this in mind, the following example script creates a textbox-field which may have line-breaks (returns) in it. However, only by using the "copy" action attached to the button is the text 'stored' in a variable which can be accessed after the dialog is closed.

```
class myDLG : UIFrame
{
    string textBuffer
    tagGroup CreateDLGSelf( object self )
    {
        number width  = 20  // line width of box
        number height = 10  // number of lines
        number length = 500 // maximum length (characters) of content

        TagGroup textBox = DLGCreateTextBox( width, height, length )
        textBox.DLGIdentifier( "textBox" )

        TagGroup StoreButton = DLGCreatePushButton( "Store" , "StoreText" )

        TagGroup DLG, DLGitems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "TestBox", DLGitems )
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( textBox )
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( StoreButton )

        return DLG
    }

    void StoreText( object self ) 
    {
        textBuffer = self.GetTextElementData( "textBox" )
    }

    string GetBufferedText( object self )
    {
        return textBuffer
    }

    object Init( object self )
    {
        return self.Super.Init( self.CreateDLGSelf() )
    }
}


// Main script
{
    object testDLG = Alloc(myDLG).Init()
    if ( testDLG.pose() )
        OKDialog( "Text:" + testDLG.GetBufferedText() )
}
```

If the dialog is *modeless* (i.e. displayed via `display()`) the fields can be directly accessed. The following script demonstrates this - and also how such a dialog could create an annotation stamp on an image.

```
class annoTool : UIFrame
{
    tagGroup CreateToolDlg( object self )
    {
        number width  = 50  // line width of box
        number height = 5   // number of lines
        number length = 300 // maximum length (characters) of content.

        TagGroup textBox = DLGCreateTextBox( width, height, length )
        textBox.DLGIdentifier("textBox")

        TagGroup CreatAnnoButton = DLGCreatePushButton( "Copy to Image" , "CreateAnno" )
        TagGroup InitTextButton = DLGCreatePushButton( "Intitialze" , "InitTextField" )

        TagGroup DLG, DLGitems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "TestBox", DLGitems )
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( textBox )
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGGroupItems( InitTextButton, CreatAnnoButton ).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)  )

        return DLG
    }

    void InitTextField( object self )
    {
        string init = ""
        init += "Date:" + GetDate(1) + "\n"
        init += "Time:" + GetTime(0) + "\n"
        init += "(c) My TEM Institute"
        self.SetTextElementData( "textBox", init )
    }

    void CreateAnno( object self ) 
    {
        image front
        string textBuffer = self.GetTextElementData("textBox")
        if ( GetFrontImage(front) )
        {
            CreateTextAnnotation( front, 0, 0, textBuffer)
        }
    }

    object Init( object self )
    {
        return self.Super.Init( self.CreateToolDlg() )
    }
}


// Main script
{
    Alloc(annoTool).Init().display( "Annotation Creater" )
}
```